# How to display a doc exported as pdf from Google drive in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

I'm using [react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper](https://github.com/RobinBobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper) to download my documents from Google drive - now I'm trying to display it in my React Native app on Android.

Here's what I've tried so far.

This seems to work:

```
        pdf = await gdrive.files.export(id, { mimeType: "application/pdf" },{responseType: 'stream'});
```

Now I'd like to display it with [react-native-pdf](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf)

Here`s my piece of React Native code

```
              <Pdf
                trustAllCerts={false}
                enablePaging={true}
                horizontal={true}
                source={{uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.reactnativegoogledocs/files/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf'}}
                onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath) => {
                    console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                }}
...
```

This works for my document "test.pdf" which has been stored locally - but how can I display the pdf I downloaded from Google docs?

I thought of using [react-native-blob-util](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util) to store the document - but how can this be achieved?

Is it possible to use this [react-native-blob-util#user-content-file-stream](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util#user-content-file-stream) - if so how can I store my downloaded document with it? Which encoding?

Or is there a way to use my downloaded document directly with react-native-pdf? That's what I found in the doc's of react-native-pdf:

```
const source = {uri:"blob:xxxxxxxx-...?offset=0&size=xxx"};
```

If this is a solution: how can I use this?

Thank you in advance for your efforts, Frank